# Google Analytics: generate report based on Location + Top events

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

We need to generate reports in Google Analytics, displaying correlation between Top Events and Location of users.

GA is connected to our backend.

Comment: This should be posted tothe webmasters forum as it is not related to coding. But regarding your question what haven you tried looking at so far?

Comment: The question is a little vague, but have you tried using secondary dimensions? You could also create a custom report that correlates the event dimensions with the location dimensions (probably using a Flat Table).